# how can login a user from android app to wordpress website without writing php code

Tags: android, wordpress, android-webview, wordpress-rest-api

I'm developing an app for a product that is already a wordpress website so the first step is to login existing users of the website to our mobile app, I need someone to guide me on how i can implement this functionality without having to write php code.

Comment: is it possible to sent get or post requests from http library  to get data or modify the data

Comment: WordPress has a built-in REST API you can use for this. Check the documentation for more details.